# Singular/Plural bei Aufzählungen

Tags: grammatical-number, list

Man betrachte folgende zwei Sätze:

> Demnach *muss* nun das Ziel und der Zweck der Regelung ermittelt werden.
>
> Demnach *müssen* nun das Ziel und der Zweck der Regelung ermittelt werden.

Welcher Satz ist hier korrekt und weshalb? Rein grammatikalisch gesehen ist wohl der zweite Satz richtig. Allerdings klingt das irgendwie holprig ...

Klar, man könnte den Satz auch anders formulieren, aber auch dann wird es nicht besser:

> Demnach *muss* nun das Ziel und *muss* nun der Zweck der Regelung ermittelt werden.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ein Blick in die Duden Grammatik (hier 7. Auflage) erhellt den Sachverhalt.

Zur **Kongruenz zwischen Subjekt und finitem Verb** wird als **Grundregel** genannt (§ 1601):

> *(Kongruenzregel I)* Das finite Verb stimmt mit dem Subjekt in Person und Numerus überein.

Darüber hinaus gibt es **Regelungen zur Kongruenz des finiten Verbs mit Reihungen**. Wenn die Reihung "gesamthaft ein (sic!) einzige Phrase" bildet, ein "komplexes Subjekt" vorliegt und die "Elemente der Reihung (...) Subjektteile" sind, und das ist in oben genanntem Beispiel der Fall, gilt u. a. folgende Regel (§ 1602):

> *(Kongruenzregel II für Subjekte mit gereihten Subjektteilen)*
>  a) Die
>   Reihung gilt gesamt als Plural, das finite Verb steht daher ebenfalls
>   im Plural.
>  b) Die 1. Person rangiert vor der 2. Person, und die 2.
>   Person rangiert vor der 3. Person.

B) soll bei dieser Betrachtung außer Acht gelassen werden. Nach a) wäre also tatsächlich der zweite Beispielsatz ("*müssen* (...) das Ziel und der Zweck (...) ermittelt werden") grammatikalisch richtig. Doch keine Regel ohne **Ausnahme** (§ 1605): "Abweichungen von Kongruenzregel II hängen mit der **Wortstellung** und mit der **Bedeutung der gereihten Subjektteile** zusammen."

Zum Einfluss der Bedeutung ist in §§ 1608-1613 mehr zu erfahren. In Bezug auf die Frage soll zunächst § 1609 näher betrachtet werden:

> Bei **formelhaften Wortpaaren ohne Artikel**(!) steht das finite Verb vor
>   allem dann im Singular, wenn das Wortpaar **inhaltlich eine Einheit**
>   ausdrückt. Wirklich feste Regeln lassen sich hier nicht aufstellen.

Es folgen Beispiele mit dem Verb in beiden Numeri, u. a.:

> Verb im Singular: Zeit *und* Geld *fehlt* uns. Positives *und*
>   Negatives *ist* zu beachten. 
>   Verb im Plural: ... die verdrehten
>   Vorstellungen, die Freund *und* Feind sich von diesem Lande *machen*.
>   Unaufhaltsam *wachsen* ... Missmut *und* Unbehagen.

Entfallen also die Artikel der Reihung, darf man sich getrost für die erste, besser klingende Variante entscheiden, da sie grammatikalisch nicht falsch ist:

> Demnach *muss* nun Ziel und Zweck der Regelung ermittelt werden.

§ 1610 hilft ebenfalls etwas weiter:

> **Je abstrakter die Bedeutung der Subjektteile** ist, desto eher neigt man dazu, das finite Verb in den Singular zu setzen.

Allerdings sei "bei gewöhnlichen Abstrakta (...) der Plural noch häufiger als der Singular":

> *(Plural)* Der Hass *und* die Gewalt *sind* immer noch da. 
>   *(Singular)* Der Hass *und* die Gewalt der Täter *wird* auf sie selber zurückfallen.

Besonders an diesem Punkt wird deutlich, dass der Duden nicht allein normativ ist, sondern gerade bei diesen Sowohl-als-auch-Fällen zu einem guten Teil deskriptiv; dass er also die Vielfalt der Sprache beschreibt, statt Regeln in Stein zu meißeln. Kurz: **Es gibt kein "grammatikalisch korrekt" an dieser Stelle** - bzw. sind beide Formulierungen richtig.

Comment: What a great answer.

Comment: *`nicht allein normativ ist, sondern gerade bei diesen Sowohl-als-auch-Fällen zu einem guten Teil deskriptiv`* -- das ist leider ***falsch*** und richtig, denn de-facto **normativ** zu sein, obwohl sein Ziel **Deskriptivität** ist (siehe [Pressemitteilung](https://www.duden.de/presse/5-000-Woerter-staerker-Der-neue-Duden-ist-da)), ist das Duden-Dilemma.

Answer (score 9):

Ja, rein grammatikalisch ist der zweite richtig, und der dritte klingt sehr schlecht. Ziel und Zweck ist aber zu einer Art festem Begriff geworden, der teils in der Einzahl verwendet wird. Daher sagt man:

> Ziel und Zweck der Übung ist …

Das Verb ist hier "ist", also Einzahl. Damit kann man vielleicht auch dein Problem lösen:

> Demnach muss nun Ziel und Zweck der Regelung ermittelt werden.

Auch möglich wäre Mehrzahl ohne Artikel … klingt meiner Ansicht nach auch stimmiger als die Ausgangssätze:

> Demnach müssen nun Ziel und Zweck der Regelung ermittelt werden.

Das ist aber rein persönliches Sprachempfinden und andere mögen mir widersprechen.
Eine andere, etwas freiere Möglichkeit wäre:

> Nun gilt es, Ziel und Zweck der Regelung zu ermitteln.

Answer (score 4):

Beide Sätze können korrekt sein.

Die Frage ist, ob die Ermittlung, die Ziel und Zweck der Regelung zu ermitteln trachtet, beides als Getrenntes auffasst, also etwa 2 Teams bilden könnte, von denen jedes eine Frage löst, oder ob es nicht doch nur zwei leicht divergierende Perspektiven auf die gleiche Sache sind, das Ziel oder auch den Zweck der Regelung zu ermitteln, was nur einer Antwort bedarf.

In der Regel ist mit "Ziel und Zweck" nur eine Sache gemeint - selbst die Möglichkeit, dass die Ziellinie des 100m Laufs von der Goldmedaille als Zweck der Veranstaltung als unterschiedlich wahrgenommen wird, ist gering. Die Benutzung zweier Worte soll lediglich rhetorisch die Angelegenheit ein wenig aufplustern, und gewichtiger wie größer erscheinen lassen, das Publikum beeindrucken und täuschen.

Die Verwendung einer Alliteration, also zweier Wörter mit gleichem Anlaut, oder hier nur: Buchstaben, unterstreicht dabei den dekorativen Gebrauch der Sprache.