# Aufzählung: Numerus und Kasus

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, style, grammatical-number, list

Es geht um folgenden Satz:

> Was ich habe, ist Mut, Entschlossenheit und der Drang, nicht auf die Nase zu fallen.

1. Die "ist"-oder-"sind"-Frage.

   Ich habe mich des folgenden Threads bedient: [Singular/Plural bei Aufzählungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4000/1224).
   Dort gefunden:

   > § 1610 Je abstrakter die Bedeutung der Subjektteile ist, desto eher neigt man dazu, das finite Verb in den Singular zu setzen.

   Abstrakt sind sie. Demnach scheint "ist" hier in Ordnung zu sein. Stimmt das?
2. "**Der** Drang" hört sich etwas komisch an. Ist es grammatikalisch korrekt?
3. Und wahrscheinlich damit verbunden: Wie holprig empfindet ihr diesen Satz?

Comment: Zu 2: Ich persönlich würde den zweiten Teil in den Akkusativ setzen, was sich nur an einer Stelle auswirkt (der → den). Zu 3: In den meisten Kontexten würde ich die Konstruktion als gestelzt empfinden und stattdessen mit *Ich habe jedoch* o. Ä. beginnen.

Comment: Nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist der Akkusativ ("den Drang") möglich, aber nur in Verbindung mit "ist". Sobald ich das Verb durch "sind" ersetze, klingt der Akkusativ sehr seltsam.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich glaube, dass Akkusativ hier falsch ist: "Was ich habe, ist [...] den Drang..."? Kann eigentlich nicht sein, oder?

Comment: @Uwe +1. Nominativ klingt nach meinem Empfinden in diesem Fall verkehrt. Ich würde ebenfalls den Akkusativ verwenden.

Comment: @Mac: Naja, *was* ist im diesem Fall ein Akkusativ, und dieser wird ausgeführt (gewissermaßen eine constructio ad sensum). Andererseits ist natürlich *Mut … und der Drang, …* das Subjekt des Satzes. In einem Fall, wo die grammatikalischen Fälle prominenter sind, klingt beides furchtbar: *Wen ich hasse, ist ihn/er.* (oder noch schlimmer: *Wen ich hasse, bin/ist ich/mich.*) Vielleicht funktioniert die Konstruktion in der Frage nur deshalb einigermaßen, weil die Fälle eben nicht klar sind. Hmm, ich glaube, ich habe gerade Frage 3 beantwortet.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Lol, ja: Frage 3 ist damit definitiv beantwortet - aber ich finde nach wie vor, dass sich das Verb dieses Satzes "ist" aufs schmerzhafteste gegen den Akkusativ sträubt...

Comment: I would think the nominative case is right in "der Drang", since it says "(Etwas) ist der Drang."

Answer (score 4):

Für mich ist das eine ganz normale Aufzählung von Dingen. Also würde ich hier den Plural verwenden, der Singular klingt für mich fürchterlich...

Wenn man ihn dann "richtig" schreibt, heißt er ja

> Was ich habe sind Mut, Entschlossenheit und der Drang, nicht auf die Nase zu fallen.

Dann klingt auch *der Drang* nicht mehr so schief :-)

Man würde ja auch nicht sagen: *Was? Spannung, Spiel und Schokolade? Das ist ja drei Dinge auf einmal!*

Answer (score 1):

Die Substantive Mut, Entschlossenheit und der Drang, nicht auf die Nase zu fallen, sind hier höchstens gewöhnliche Abstrakte. In dem vorliegenden Sinn von „Eigenschaften haben“ würde ich sie nicht mal als Abstrakte werten, aber darüber kann man streiten.

Jedenfalls ist die Regel bezüglich der Abstrakta eine deskriptive. Es sind also beide Varianten tolerierbar.

Persönlich würde ich hier eher nach der Einheit der Reihung gehen (wird auch in der Frage behandelt): Je nachdem, wie stark man diese drei Eigenschaften als Einheit sieht, sollte man Singular bzw. Plural verwenden. Für mich selbst also Plural.

Comment: Interessant. Ich finde den Singular absolut in Ordnung in OP's Satz. Kann aber nicht mal sagen, warum.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Singular/Plural**

Wie du schon gefunden hast, ist der Singular in dieser Aufzählung in Ordnung. Der Plural ist es auch. Meines Erachtens betont der Plural mehr die Einheit der Dinge (»Ich habe drei Dinge. Diese Dinge sind«), während der Singular mehr die einzelnen Dinge selbst hervorhebt (»Ich habe das, das und das«).

**2. Akkusativ oder Nominativ beim *Drang***

Das kann man auch nicht wirklich entscheiden; nur Dativ und Genitiv sind auf jeden Fall falsch. Ich persönlich würde den Drang in den Akkusativ setzen, denn »ich habe *den Drang*«. Andererseits klingt das wiederum umso schräger, je näher der Drang dem *ist* kommt. Ich würde auch im Plural beide Fälle zulassen, dort aber möglicherweise in Richtung Nominativ tendieren.

**3. Ist der Satz holprig?**

**Ja!** Definitiv. Du merkst es bereits, und Wrzlprmft hat is in seinem Kommentar noch etwas ausgebreitet: Der erste Teil lässt einen Akkusativ erwarten (»ich habe den Drang«), während der zweite Teil grammatikalisch einen Nominativ fordert; außerdem erscheint das ganze unnötig kompliziert.

»Was ich habe« soll meines Erachtens nur zusätzlich betonen, dass man das hat. Reichen würde aber vollkommen

> Ich habe Mut, Entschlossenheit und den Drang, nicht auf die Nase zu fallen.

Wenn dieser Satz in einer Rede gesagt wird, kann man ihn durch die Artikulation hervorheben. Wenn er in einem romanartigen Werk stehen soll, könnte man es folgendermaßen lösen:

> »Ich habe«, betonte der Zwerg, »Mut, Entschlossenheit und den Drang, nicht auf die Nase zu fallen!«

Und zuletzt, sollte der Satz in einem Brief oder ähnlichem stehen (vielleicht bewirbt sich ja jemand um bei Tolkiens Ringgefährten mitzumachen?) würde ein einfaches Ausrufezeichen am Satzende reichen.

Answer (score -1):

Zu Frage 2:

Es muss natürlich "den Drang" heißen. Das Objekt von dem Verb "haben" steht immer im Akkusativ.

(Frage zum testen: "Wen oder was habe ich?" -> "Den Drang")

Comment: Scheint eine Privatmeinung zu sein ;) Schließlich gehen drei bisher gegebene Antworten in die andere Richtung. (Was nicht heißt, dass ich *den* Drang nicht für besser hielte; nur eben nicht für *ausschließlich richtig*.)

Comment: Nein, ist nicht meine Privatmeinung, sorry.
Man findet zugegebenermaßen im Internet leider nicht so einfach Internetseiten auf denen die Kasus von Objekten bestimmter Verben stehen. Auf http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Objekt/Akkusativ.html steht, dass man nach dem Akkusativ-Objekt mit "Wen oder was" fragen kann. Angenommen es könnte Nominativ ("Der Drang") sein, dann müsste folgende Frage korrekt sein:
"Wer oder was habe ich?" (->"Der Drang")
Mit "Wer oder was" fragt man aber nach dem Nominativ, also nach dem Subjekt. Das Subjekt ist in diesem Satz allerdings "ich".

Comment: Nein, so meine ich das nicht. Im Akkusativ steht selbstredend das »was« am Satzanfang. Die Aufzählung dahinter *kann* aber sowohl im Nominativ als auch im Akkusativ formuliert werden; ersteres wenn man sie als nicht mehr zum Satz davor dazugehörig empfindet. (Ich sehe es aber auch so – siehe meine Antwort –, dass der Akkusativ hier weniger schlecht ist.)