# Is it "Es seien" or "Es sei"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, sentence-structure, grammaticality, mathematics

Which one is grammatically correct?

a)

> Es sei A eine Menge, n eine natürliche Zahl und q eine rationale Zahl. Dann gilt ...

b)

> Es seien A eine Menge, n eine natürliche Zahl und q eine rationale Zahl. Dann gilt ...

Such formulations could occur in mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

#### One symbol

If you have only one symbol per category, you use the singular form:

> Es **sei** A eine Menge, n eine natürliche Zahl und q eine rationale Zahl.

The sentence could be re-written as follows:

> Es **sei** A eine Menge, und es **sei** n eine natürliche Zahl, und es **sei** q eine rationale Zahl.

#### More than one symbol

If you have more than one symbol per category, you use the plural form:

> Es **seien** A, B und C Mengen, n und m natürliche Zahlen und q und s rationale Zahlen.

This sentence could be re-written as follows:

> Es **seien** A, B und C Mengen, und es **seien** n und m natürliche Zahlen und es **seien** q und s rationale Zahlen.

#### Mixture

If you have a mixture, you can do it as follows:

> Es **sei** A eine Menge und n eine natürliche Zahl, und es **seien** q und r rationale Zahlen.

This sentence could be re-written as follows:

> Es **sei** A eine Menge, und es **sei** n eine natürliche Zahl, und es **seien** q und r rationale Zahlen.

Comment: A very minor point, but is the penultimate sentence entirely correct? The first half is fine (‘Es sei A eine Menge und n eine natürliche Zahl’), but shouldn’t the second half read: ‚und **es** seien q und r rationale Zahlen‘, with an additional ‚es‘? Because of ‚und‘, I’m not sure the subject can be elided.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkOxford. I added the _es_. However, I think that the _es_ can be left out in all the sentences.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, both forms are possible, but in general, the rules for the agreement of a verb form with a sequence of subjects are somewhat vague. See for instance [Singular/Plural bei Aufzählungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen).