# Erfolgen/Finden + Aufzählung mit und

Tags: grammatical-number

> Nachdem die einzelnen Angebote betrachtet wurden, **erfolgt/erfolgen** abschließend
>   ein Vergleich der Produkte und ein Vergleich der Preise.

Wird an dieser Stelle der Plural oder Singular verwendet? Ich würde Singular bevorzugen, allerdings markiert Word das Wort blau und schlägt den Plural vor. Was ist an dieser Stelle richtig? Neben dem Wort "erfolgt" tritt das gleiche Problem bei dem Wort "stattfinden", also "findet/finden ein Vergleich und ein Vergleich... statt". Kann man den Singular verwenden wenn Vergleich in beiden Fällen auch im Singular steht?

> Nachdem die einzelnen Angebote betrachtet wurden, **erfolgt/erfolgen** abschließend
>   ein Vergleich der Produkte und mehrere Preisanalysen.

Hier muss es Plural sein oder?

Answer (score -5):

Da jeweils immer zwei Sachen `folgen`, ist in beiden Fällen Plural zu verwenden.

Comment: Sind sie sich da sicher? Bei der Verwendung der Konstruktion "X sowie Y hat/haben" ist auch der Singular möglich. "erfolgen" bedeutet laut duden "geschehen, eintreten, vor sich gehen". Bei der Beschreibung von Abläufen verwende ich das Wort häufig.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen

Comment: erfolgen, folgen ist vielleicht Geschmackssache, ich bevorzuge die einfachere Form, weil ich denke, dass sich der Sinn dadurch nicht ändert.

Comment: Wenn man nicht weiß, was das nachgefragte Wort heißen soll, sollte man keine Antwort schreiben. Die Aussage *»Ich frage mich, was das heißen soll«* bringt dem Fragesteller genau gar nichts.