# Doubt about spielt/spielen

Tags: grammatical-number, conjugation

What is the difference between:

1. Nina **spielt** gerne Fußball
2. Nina und Amy **spielen** gerne Fußball.

According to [spielen](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-spielen.html), second person conjunction of spielen is spielt.
So why are we conjugating it two different ways?

Is there a rule about plurals I am missing?

Comment: It’s third person plural. Did you really intend to write second person?

Comment: I consider this as a duplicate of [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/44721/1696). Any contrary opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the numerus. For simplicity, I will drop in the example sentences the adverb *gerne*, as then we are dealing with the same verbs in German (*spielen*) and English (*to play*).

**Singular**

1. Nina *spielt* Fußball.

   → Nina *plays* football.

Here, Nina *is* one person. Therefore, the third-person (not second-person, as you wrote) singular forms must be used (*spielt* = *plays*).

**Plural**

2. Nina und Amy *spielen* Fußball.

   → Nina and Amy *play* football.

Here, Nina and Amy *are* more than one person. Therefore, the third-person plural forms must be used (*spielen* = *like*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference between 3rd person singular and 3rd person plural in German:

> Er/sie/es spielt vs. sie (Plural) spielen.

Comment: In case it's not clear, when you combine two nouns with *und*, the result is plural. The same holds in English, "Nina like**s** to play football/soccer" vs. "Nina and Amy like to play football/soccer."