# Schwierigkeiten bei Rilkes Versen

Tags: meaning-in-context, gender, grammatical-number

Beim Lesen eines Gedichts von Rilke bin ich über eine mir zu verwirrende Konstruktion gestolpert. Da sind die Verse:

> Nicht mehr versuch ich, dich, wenn das Kommende wogt,
>   zu erkennen. Alle die großen
>   Bilder in mir, im Fernen erfahrene Landschaft,
>   Städte und Türme und Brücken und un-
>   vermutete Wendung der Wege
>   und das Gewaltige jener von Göttern
>   einst durchwachsenen Länder:
>   **steigt** zur Bedeutung in mir
>   deiner, Entgehende, an.

Und zwar liegen meine zwei Schwierigkeiten in den letzten zwei Versen:

1) worauf bezieht sich das Pronomen "deiner"?

2) wer ist das Subjket von "steigt"?

Wäre "deiner" ein "deines", dann hätte ich es einfach als "dein Bild" verstanden. Aber diese maskuline Endung verstehe ich gar nicht.

Wie ich die Verse verstehe, hätte das Verb "steigen" im Plural stehen müssen, weil sein Subjekt die ganze Aufzählung der vorigen Verse wäre (die Bilder, Städte, Türme, Brücke, Wendung, das Gewaltige).
Freilich kann sein Subjekt "deiner" sein: aber dann bin ich im Dunkeln, da ich mir nicht sicher bin, worauf sich "deiner" bezieht.
Ich sehe nur noch zwei weitere Möglichkeiten, diese Endung von "steigt" auszulegen. Entweder würde ich das Verb als Imperativ von 2. Person Plural verstehen (wo sich der Dichter dann zu den Bildern wendete), oder dann als wäre davor ein weggelassenes "all das" zu lesen.

Comment: Diesen Vers richtig zu deuten müsstest du, Fragender, uns seines, des Verses, Begleiter - die Sätze zuvor und hernach - noch verkünden!

Comment: "Du im Voraus/ verlorne Geliebte, Nimmergekommene,/ nicht weiß ich, welche Töne dir lieb sind./ Nicht mehr versuch ich, dich, wenn das Kommende wogt,/ zu erkennen. Alle die großen/ Bilder in mir, im Fernen erfahrene Landschaft,/ 
Städte und Türme und Brücken und un-/ vermutete Wendung der Wege/ und das Gewaltige jener von Göttern/ einst durchwachsenen Länder:/ steigt zur Bedeutung in mir/ deiner, Entgehende, an."

Comment: Hab ich mir doch gedacht, dass eine Frau dahintersteht!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um die Sache zu erleichtern, gebe ich hier mal das Gedicht in seinem originalen (?) Umbruch wieder (oder was man so findet im Internet, ein Buch habe ich grade nicht zur Hand.)

> Du im Voraus
>   verlorne Geliebte, Nimmergekommene,
>   nicht weiß ich, welche Töne dir lieb sind.
>   Nicht mehr versuch ich, dich, wenn das Kommende wogt,
>   zu erkennen. Alle die großen
>   Bilder in mir, im Fernen erfahrene Landschaft,
>   Städte und Türme und Brücken und un-
>   vermutete Wendung der Wege
>   und das Gewaltige jener von Göttern
>   einst durchwachsenen Länder:
>   **steigt** zur Bedeutung in mir
>   deiner, Entgehende, an.
>   
>   Ach, die Gärten bist du,
>   ach, ich sah sie mit solcher
>   Hoffnung. Ein offenes Fenster
>   im Landhaus - , und du tratest beinahe
>   mir nachdenklich heran. Gassen fand ich, -
>   du warst sie gerade gegangen,
>   und die Spiegel manchmal der Läden der Händler
>   waren noch schwindlich von dir und gaben erschrocken
>   mein zu plötzliches Bild. - Wer weiß, ob derselbe
>   Vogel nicht hinklang durch uns
>   gestern, einzeln, im Abend?

**1) Deiner**

Für mich gehört "deiner" zu "Bedeutung", also "steigt zur Bedeutung deiner in mir an". Was man weniger poetisch wohl mit "verdichten sich zu dem, was du für mich bedeutest" wiedergeben könnte.

**2) Steigt**

Mein Eindruck ist, dass mit "steigen" statt "steigt" das Gedicht nicht schlechter wäre. Oder einen Satzfehler weniger hätte.

Sollte es sich also wirklich um einen Satzfehler handeln?

(Dies zu erraten, oh Leser, bräuchte es nun einen Gang in die Halle der Bücher, wo, Seiten, bedruckte, ihr stehet und wartet auf die euch greifende Hand. Denn nur auf gelbem Papier sagt uns die Schwärze des Druckers, was wohl dem Dichter im Sinn stand, gab er die Verse in Satz.)

Beim mehrmaligen Lesen ertappe ich mich dabei, dass das "Alle die großen Bilder...", in Verbindung mit der Aufzählung von allerlei Dingen und Eindrücken, bei mir zu einem großen Brei von "alles" verschwimmt. Vielleicht ging es Rilke (oder dem Sprachzentrum seines Hirns) auch so, und darum hat er unten, verloren habend den Faden, den roten, "steigt" geschrieben?

Rhythmisch finde ich "steigt" übrigens deutlich besser. Auch dies mag noch dazu beigetragen haben, dass Rilke (oder war es am Ende nur der Setzer?) am Satzende den Numerus verwechselt hat.

Behelfsmäßig könnte man noch versuchen, nach "Wege" das Fehlen eines Kommas zu unterstellen. Dann ließe sich "steigt" nur auf "das Gewaltige" beziehen. Inhaltlich wird der Sinn aber nicht besser, eher schlechter.

**3) Was dachten andere?**

Vielleicht hilft es auch, zu sehen, wie andere mit dem Problem umgegangen sind. In einer englischen Übersetzung (von Rosenthal) finden wir:

> You from the outset
>   Lost Beloved, my Never-Arrived,
>   I’ve no idea, none, what tones are dear to you.
>   No longer do I hope, when the moment wells up,
>   To recognize you. All the vast
>   Scenes inside me, so far off, so familiar,
>   Cities and towers and bridges and un-
>   Foreseen winding of ways
>   And that stormy world where gods
>   Once strode through the lands:
>   All this within me presses toward one meaning:
>   You, vanishing.

Übersetzer Rosenthal hat also "steigen" (Plural) gelesen.

Und weil die Komparatistik so erkenntnisbringend ist, hier noch die gleiche Strophe auf Ungarisch von Hajnal Gábor:

> Te, már előre
>   elvesztett Kedves, Soha-Elnemjövő,
>   nem tudom, milyen hang kedves tenéked.
>   Már meg se kisérlem, ha forrong az eljövendő,
>   hogy felismerjelek. Mind a
>   nagy képek bennem, a messzi megismert tájban,
>   városok és tornyok és hidak és el-
>   kanyarodó nemvárt utcák
>   és a nagysága ama egykoron
>   istenekkel benőtt országoknak:
>   mindez a Te jelentéseddé
>   tágul bennem, Menekülő.

Meine Versuche, festzustellen, ob hier Plural oder Singular verstanden wurden, halten noch an... sollte ein fähiger Finnougrist des Weges kommen, so reiche er seine Hand uns zur Hilfe! Ich kann aber hier festhalten, dass auch in der ungarischen Version "deine" sich auf "Bedeutung" (jelentés) bezieht. (Eine grobe Übersetzung der letzten zwei Zeilen wäre wohl: "All das zu deiner Bedeutung es dehnt sich zu mir aus, Flucht.")

---

Rilke, Die Gedichte. Insel Verlag, Frankfurt a.M. 1986. 1906 bis 1926. Vollendetes

Comment: zu 2) "In der Tat ergibt sich der Eindruck, dass mit "steigen" statt "steigt" das Gedicht nicht schlechter wäre. Oder einen Satzfehler weniger hätte. Siehe "https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen Es gibt da also keine ganz klare Regel.

Comment: @Javatasse   Nach kurzem Protestgefühl war ich geneigt, dir Recht zu geben: *Es muss der Hund, die Katz, die Maus, der Habicht doch zugrundegeh'n.* - Mindestens in poetischem Sprachgebrauch ist es wohl akzeptabel, das Verb nur mit Einzeldingen einer Reihung zu kongruieren; vielleicht besonders dann, wenn die Aktivität, die das Verb ausdrückt, für jedes der Subjekte isoliert gedacht ist. Hund, Katze, Maus und Habicht - jeder stirbt hier ja allein. Jedoch, jedoch: Rilke fängt seine Liste an mit: **"Alle die großen Bilder in mir..."**, und das ruft streng nach der Mehrzahl.

Comment: Allerdings sind die großen Bilder weit weg. Da kommt dann hinterher, nach dem Luftholen, das bedeutungsstarke "und das Gewaltige jener von Göttern einst durchwachsenen Länder". Mir scheint auch, dass die "durchwachsenen Länder" sich ein bisschen auf die Landschaften, Städte und Brücken rückwärts beziehen. Wenn ich das auf "steigen" ändere, dann finde ich es weniger ausdrucksvoll.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn da ein Singular steht, kann sich das nur auf ein einziges Subjekt im vorhergehenden Text beziehen (auch wenn da ein mit dichterischer Freiheit begründbarer Doppelpunkt dazwischen ist): "das Gewaltige"

Ein bißchen die Wortreihenfolge verändern und lyrische Dekoration entfernen führt zu:

> ... und das Gewaltige steigt zur Bedeutung deiner an.

Man darf annehmen, dass die weiteren mit "und" verknüpften Satzbestandteile gar nicht zum Prädikat gehören, sondern nur "das Gewaltige" näher erläutern - Etwa im Sinne von "Hammer und Meißel und das Loch in der Wand ist geritzt", was ja auch keine Aufzählung ist.

*Deiner* ist hier ein Genitiv, genauer wahrscheinlich ein Genitivus Explicativus, und heißt einfach "von dir". Rilke hat hier möglicherweise den Genitiv gewählt, weil es den auch als "Superlativus" gibt ("Das Buch der Bücher") und er deshalb in der Doppelbedeutung so schön passt.

Comment: Am gängigsten in Beziehung auf "deiner" könnte der Ausdruck "mit Sehnsucht erwarte ich deiner" sein.

Comment: Es widerspricht dem Geist des Gedichts, das Verb nur auf *das Gewaltige* zu beziehen. Es ist viel natürlicher und dem Geist des Gedichts angemessener, anzunehmen, dass die gesamte Reihe von Dingen, die Rilke aufzählt, einfließt in "die Bedeutung deiner in mir". Hier nur *das Gewaltige* zu sehen und die anderen, sanfteren Dinge wegzulassen, kommt mir geradzu wie ein Vergewaltigung des Gedichtes sowie des ausgedrückten Gefühls vor. Und wozu hätte Rilke dann die anderen schönen Sachen überhaupt erst aufzählen sollen. Die ganze Strophe zielt ja darauf hin, dass alles an die tolle Frau erinnert.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich glaube, du hast meine Antwort nicht verstanden - Eine grammatikalische Beziehung und eine semantische Beziehung ist was anderes. Und das "bezieht sich nicht" ist eben nur im rein grammatikalischen zu sehen. So wie sich in meinem Beispielsatz ja Hammer und Meißel *grammatikalisch* nicht auf das Prädikat beziehen, aber *semantisch* trotzdem zum  Loch in der Wand führen (Ich gebe zu, mein Beispiel ist nicht sehr romantisch)

Comment: @tofro   Ah, okay. Danke für die Erläuterung. Ja, grammatisch kann (und will) ich dir nicht widersprechen. Allerdings ist der rein technisch-grammatische (formalsyntaktische) Bezug ja vielleicht gerade irrelevant, wenn Rilke nämlich - aus wohl übergeordneten Gründen - die üblichen Grammatikregeln übergeht. Was hier, meine ich jetzt, wohl der Fall ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich glaube eben *nicht*, dass Rilkes Gedicht an dieser Stelle ungrammatisch ist (genauso, wie mein "Hammer-und-Meissel-Satz" es ja auch nicht ist). Nicht alles, was mit "und" verbunden ist, ist eine Aufzählung.

Answer (score 2):

Ich schreibe jetzt auch eine Antwort, da das in den Kommentaren unübersichtlich wird.

In Bezug auf das "deiner" dürften die Antworten von **tofro** und **Christian Geiselmann** den Sachverhalt ausreichend beschreiben.

Den wegen dem "steigt" diskutierten Abschnitt würde ich so aufteilen:

> Alle die großen Bilder in mir

wir mit

> im Fernen erfahrene Landschaft,
>   Städte und Türme und Brücken und un-
>   vermutete Wendung der Wege

noch weiter spezifiziert. Diese 3 Zeilen sind von der Bedeutung her also eher ein Nebensatz.
Zusätzlich wird die **im Fernen erfahrene Landschaft** durch **Städte und Türme und Brücken** und **unvermutete Wendung der Wege** ebenfalls weiter spezifiziert und ist im gleichen Sinn ein weiter untergeordneter Nebensatz.

Das darauf folgende

> und das Gewaltige jener von Göttern
>   einst durchwachsenen Länder

schließt sich an "Alle die großen Bilder in mir" an.

Wie sich das grammtisch verhält wird in [Singular/Plural bei Aufzählungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen) diskutiert. Der wichtigste Punkt aus der Antwort dort könnte hier sein, dass es sich bei "das Gewaltige" um ein eher abstraktes Konzept handelt, mit dem nach einer Aufzählung ein Verb im Singular eher akzeptiert wird.
"Alle die großen Bilder in mir" ist andererseits zweifellos Plural.
Auch eine Rolle spielt die Verwendung der Substantive "Landschaft" und "Wendung" ebenfalls im Singular. Wären diese im Plural, würde man um "steigen" wohl nicht herum kommen.
Allerdings denke ich nicht, dass sich das "steigt" nur auf "das Gewaltige" beziehen soll, sondern dass die Bilder mit einbezogen sind.

Dafür das dort trotzdem "steigt" verwendet wird gibt es aus meiner Sicht zwei Gründe. Zum einen ist von dem Satz bis zum Doppelpunkt "das Gewaltige" viel präsenter, speziell weil es durch das "jener von Göttern einst durchwachsenen Länder" noch weiter hervorgehoben wird.
Zum anderen möchte Rilke wohl ausdrücken, dass etwas in ihm steigt. Nicht mehrere Dinge, sondern etwas zusammengehörendes, wie ein Gefühl oder eine Stimmung.

Comment: Reasonable argumentation.