# a, b, c ist die Basis / a, b, c sind die Basis

Tags: grammatical-number

Wenn man mehrere Dinge als Grundlage aufzählt, sagt man dann
***a, b, c ist die Basis***
oder 
***a, b, c sind die Basis***
?

> Kreativität, Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit sind die Basis für seinen Erfolg.

Comment: Bitte antwortet nicht in den Kommentaren.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mit *und* koordinierte Substantive können in so einer Prädikation auf zwei Weisen konstruiert werden, entweder einzeln oder als Kollektiv (zumindest in diesem Fall, da es sich um Abstrakta handelt – [kompliziertere Analysen](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4012/35111) sind möglich):

- > {a, b, c} ist als Gesamtheit P.
- > (a ist P) und (b ist P) und (c ist P).

Manchmal macht das einen Unterschied:

> Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit sind ganz verschieden
>
> *Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit ist ganz verschieden

In deinem Beispiel geht beides, weil beide Interpretationen möglich (und nahe beieinander) sind: Mit *sind* sind alle drei einzeln relevant, mit *ist* würde man die Kombination als die Basis betrachten.

Theoretisch würde also *ist* implizieren, dass nur alle drei zusammen die Basis bilden, zwei alleine aber möglicherweise nicht ausreichen.  In der Praxis wird ein solch feiner Unterschied allerdings kaum Berücksichtigung finden und eher als Haarspalterei durchgehen.

Allerdings: wie im Kommentar von @0xC0000022L angemerkt, klingt auch meiner Meinung nach die *sind*-Variante natürlicher, weil hier *Wissen, Zuverlässigkeit und Kreativität* nicht als einheitlicher Begriff, sondern individuell aufgefasst werden; anders zB.

> Gutes Essen und Trinken ist die Basis einer gelungenen Party

Comment: Ich muss zugeben, je öfter ich es lese, desto akzeptabler kommt mir "Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit ist ganz verschieden" vor. Weiß jemand darüber mehr?

Comment: Dazu fallen mir nur Umformulierungen an: "A und B sind ganz verschieden (voneinander)" gegenüber "A ist ganz verschieden von B".

Comment: Ich sehe die Variante "Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit ist ganz verschieden" als falsch an und korrigiere solche Formulierungen wo immer möglich. Kannst du eine Quelle zum Nachlesen liefern?

Comment: @Wolf eben nicht. Logisch gesehen halte ich es auch für falsch, aber ich kann es als Konstruktion irgendwie nicht ganz verwerfen. Als Verballhornung von "ist ganz verschieden von", unter dem Einfluss oder so.

Comment: @phipsgabler ich habe die Regel gefunden, dass bei unterschiedlichem Numerus die Pluralform zu nutzen ist

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4012/35111

Answer (score 7):

### Die Regel

Eine Aufzählung im Subjekt *oder* Objekt erfordert ein gebeugtes Verb im Plural, damit ist

> Kreativität, Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit sind die Basis für seinen Erfolg.

korrekt und ebenso die Umstellung:

> Die Basis für seinen Erfolg sind Kreativität, Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit.

### Das unangenehme Gefühle dabei

Ich denke, dass unser unangenehme Gefühl bei der Verwendung von „ist“ oder „sein“ auf die damit implizierten Gleichsetzung von einer Mehrzahl mit einer Einzahl zurückgeht. Auch wenn man die Regel also kennt, wird man mit manchen solcher Sätze einfach nicht glücklich. Deshalb greift man gern zu alternativen Verben.

> Kreativität, Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit bilden die Basis für seinen Erfolg.

bzw.

> Seine Erfolgsbasis besteht aus Kreativität, Wissen und Zuverlässigkeit.

### Meine Quellen

- [Schwierigkeiten bei der Kongruenz - Schwierigkeiten bei der Kongruenz -](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Schwierigkeiten_bei_der_Kongruenz)

  - Insbesondere [**Subjekt und Prädikativum mit unterschiedlichem Numerus**](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Schwierigkeiten_bei_der_Kongruenz/Schwierigkeiten-bei-der-Kongruenz-10)
- [*Die Mehrzahl der Studenten kommt* oder *kommen zur Versammlung?* — Kongruenz von Subjekt und Verb](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3150)
- [LEOs deutsche Grammatik: 1.3.2.2.1](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Verb/Kategorien/Numerus-Person/Kongruenz.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde folgendes vorschlagen:

a, b, c **bilden** die Basis

Comment: Und warum würdest du es so vorschlagen? Vorschläge sind gut, aber du musst es auch begründen können WARUM es so ist.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Hmm, da hast du natürlich Recht! Allerdings muss ich zugeben, dass ich im Begründen von sprachlichen Feinheiten absolut ungeübt bin. Meine Begründung wäre Sprachgefühl und Erfahrung - was beides aber keinen Mehrwert hat....
Ich sehe aber gerade, dass Wolf mein Besispiel (schon vor mir?!)  aufgeführt hat, damit wäre die Antwort ohnehin hinfällig...