# Numerus des finiten Verbs bei zwei mit "beziehungsweise" verbundenen Subjekten, davon eines im Singular und eines im Plural

Tags: grammaticality, conjugation

Wenn wir zwei Subjekte haben und das zweite Subjekt mit "bzw." mit dem ersten verbunden ist um das erste Subjekt zu präzisieren, bezieht sich das Verb auf das erste oder das zweite Subjekt?

> Jedes Haus bzw. alle Bewohner des Hauses *ist* gut mit Wasser und Lebensmitteln versorgt.

> Jedes Haus bzw. alle Bewohner des Hauses *sind* gut mit Wasser und Lebensmitteln versorgt.

Da das erste Subjekt im Singular und das zweite im Plural steht, muss hier das Verb im Singular oder Plural stehen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular/Plural bei Aufzählungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufz%c3%a4hlungen)

Comment: Im Satz *Da das erste Subjekt im Singular und das zweite im Plural stehen* gilt die gleiche Regel: es muss *im Plural **steht*** heißen, da die beiden Subjekte keine Einheit bilden und sich das Verb deshalb nur nach der Phrase *das zweite [Subjekt]* (Singular) richtet.

Comment: Titel geändert, da die Rolle von *beziehungsweise* hier (mit) entscheidend für die Antwort ist und die Frage so auch klarer von der bereits verlinkten vorbestehenden Frage abgegrenzt wird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn das finite Verb von einer Reihung abhängt, gilt die Regel (siehe Duden-Grammatik, § 1602):

- Wenn die Reihung eine Einheit bildet (komplexes Subjekt), steht das Verb im Plural.
- Wenn die Reihung keine Einheit bildet (z.B. bei Verbindungen mit *beziehungsweise* wie hier), richtet sich das Verb nach dem **näher stehenden** Subjekt.

Das heißt als Merkhilfe: wenn das letzte Element einer Reihung im Plural steht, steht das finite Verb im Normalfall auch im Plural, wenn es auf die Reihung folgt, egal nach welcher der o.g. Regeln. Auf ein Subjekt(teil) im Plural folgt mithin eigentlich nie ein finites Verb im Singular (von etwaigen Ausnahmefällen abgesehen).

Entscheidend wird die Regel jedoch, wenn die Reihung umgekehrt wäre:

> Alle Bewohner des Hauses bzw. jedes Haus ist gut mit Wasser und Lebensmitteln versorgt.

Auch hier richtet sich der Numerus des Verbs nach dem nächst stehenden Subjekt, dass wäre in diesem Fall *jedes Haus*.